# Faça um algoritmo que retorne uma lista com as palavras mais longas de uma lista de palavras

Tags: javascript, testes

Faça um algoritmo que retorne uma lista com as palavras mais longas de uma lista de palavras.

a um teste automatizado

eu tentei esse código

```js
function longestWords(words) {
  var longest = "";

  for (var word of words) {
    if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
  }

  return longest;
}
```

mas ele so me retorna 1 das palavras

### Exemplo

```js
longestWords(['oi', 'tudo', 'bem']) // ['tudo']
longestWords(['Javascript', 'é', 'show']) // ['Javascript']
longestWords(["aba", "aa", "ad", "vcd", "aba"]) // ["aba", "vcd", "aba"]
```

Comment: Filter ou reduce podem ser bom ... ou  programar um em um loop e retornar um novo array

Comment: tentei um for off mas sempre me retorna vazio

Comment: Expected: ["zzzzzz", "abcdef", "aaaaaa"]
    Received: ""

Comment: Então não é um array ja com as palavras! Uma palavra é passada por um parametro da função só então é verificada após a segunda palavra informada é maior que a anterior e assim suscetivamente e mostrar as maiores em um array..Se eu não estivr engando. No entanto sua pergunta ficou vaza demais sem muita informação adicional e onde nao compreendeu a fazer.

Comment: tentei esse código aqui, mas ele so me retorna uma das palavras queria que r:   function longestWords(words) {
    

    var longest = "";
    for (var word of words) {
        if (word.length > longest.length) longest = word;
    }
    return longest;}

Answer (score -1):

Seu código faz total sentido. A única coisa que faltou foi percorrer o array novamente pegando todas as outras palavras que tenham o comprimento igual àquela que vc achou.

Para isto vc poderia usar um filter. Ficaria assim:

```js
function longestWords(words) {
  let longest = '';

  for (const word of words) {
    if (word.length > longest.length) {
      longest = word;
    }
  }

  return words.filter((word) => word.length === longest.length);
}

console.log(longestWords(['oi', 'tudo', 'bem'])); // ['tudo']
console.log(longestWords(['Javascript', 'é', 'show'])); // ['Javascript']
console.log(longestWords(['aba', 'aa', 'ad', 'vcd', 'aba'])); // ["aba", "vcd", "aba"]
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function longestWords(words) {
    
    let str = words;
    let longest = "";
    let cont = 1
    let maioresPalavras = 0
    let mostra = "";
    
    for (var word of str) {
        if (word.length > longest.length){
            cont++
            longest = word
        
        }else {
            if (cont > maioresPalavras) {
                maioresPalavras = cont;
              mostra = longest;
            }
           
            cont = 1;
    }
    return mostra;
    
}
}
```